# How to extract random 2 words from middle of the each line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

i have few line like this

> why is my airbrush not spraying paint
> why is painting so hard
> why does my ceiling look patchy after painting

I used to remove the first word using this function in notepad++

```
^\w+\s(.)
\1
```

with regular expression

but my question is , how to remove the last word from each line at notepad++?

Comment: is the last word something between an space and a newLine?

Comment: The title differs from your question in the further description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your sentences in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps *to remove the last word from each line at notepad++*:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\s\w+$`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- Check *Wrap around*
- Search mode: *Regular expression*
- Click on *Replace All*

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted. You should also consider voting it up.